# How to extract non argument part of URL from page with PHP

Tags: php, php-7.3

I have a series of 3rd party scripts/plugins that wind up with me having a URL with a variable embedded that I need to retrieve (eg: /880/). I have not been able to find another way to reliably interact with this. I'm not too worried about other users fiddling the URL value as there are other security controls present that limits requests to a small group of privileged logged in users before any URL interpretation happens.

In the example below, the component whose value I need to obtain is '880'

How would I go about obtaining this?

`https://domainurl.com/parent-location/child-location/entry/880/?gvid=1774`

I'm retrieving the url with this:

```
$protocol_https = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTPS', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$host = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_HOST', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$request_uri = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_URI', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
if(strlen($request_uri) == 0)
{
    $request_uri = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'SCRIPT_NAME', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    $query_string = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'QUERY_STRING', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    if($query_string)
    {
        $request_uri .= '?' . $query_string;
    }
}
$full_url = ($protocol_https ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $host . $request_uri;
```

Where to from here?

Comment: Have you tried using `explode()` on `$request_uri`, splitting it by `/`?

Comment: No - still working out what I'm doing in PHP to be honest. 
That looks like what I'm after. works just like an array afterwards.

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be tested by others. Show your attempts on how to read/access the value `880` from the URL given.

Comment: That example is reproducible, and the question was answered. Weighing in after a suitable answer has been given, as the first comment no less, is what makes for distasteful user experience.  Good one.